# determine character cell size of a monospaced TrueType font for xterm

Tags: x11, truetype, xterm

Given an arbitrary monospaced TrueType font and an arbitrary size, as in

```
xterm -fa "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono:size=14"
```

I want to add a geometry specification so that the xterm fills some fraction of the full width and height of the display. I can compute the number of lines and columns when I know the xterm character cell size. Is there a way to compute this cell size given a font name and size as in the `-fa` option above?

I'm thinking of ripping the xterm sources apart to find where the appropriate computation is performed. But my X11 programming skills are substandard at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do X programming ;)

```
bash$ xterm -fa "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono:size=14" -geometry 40x10 \
    -e 'xwininfo -id $WINDOWID | egrep "(Width|Height)" > /tmp/winfo1'
bash$ xterm -fa "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono:size=14" -geometry 80x20 \
    -e 'xwininfo -id $WINDOWID | egrep "(Width|Height)" > /tmp/winfo2'
```

Now you have two files with dimensions in pixels, including any padding. In my case they are 444×224 and 884×444. From this one could compute the cell size of 11×22 pixels, and 4 pixels for padding.

Note this does not include any WM decorations. I think any method of finding those would be WM-specific. In my case I need to look at the grandparent window size (do `xwininfo -id $something -tree | fgrep Parent` twice).

Comment: Kids, listen up: this is why in school we learn to solve two equations with two unknowns :-)